# React Native Mobile App also working on Web and Desktop

Tags: react-native

Does React Native support Web and Desktop targets?

I would like to build the main version of app as mobile.

Would it be possible to compile the same mobile app, maybe with minor modifications for Web and Desktop?

The user experience for the secondary use cases - Web and Desktop doesn't matter much, I need just the app more or less in a working state and it will be enough. Does React Native allows that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Web, you can use [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)